# Serious perfomance problems after hosting company installed Nginx! Can I unistall it?

Tags: nginx

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

We have had perfomance problems for the last few days. Today, when I tried to re-index - I got the following Error:

> 504 Gateway Time-out nginx

### I remember we had problems last time the hosting installed Nginx and things improved once they removed it. They don't want to unistall it this time though (instead they want access to the Magento Admin panel so that they can reprodruce the problem which will be difficult because it happens intermittenly). Is it safe for me to remove Nginx myself? Why is it that it is causing problems for us? Anything we can try to fix this would be helpful.

Additional info:

I didn't explain things correctly...the re-indexing while inconvenient is not the problem! **What I'm looking at more is the increased load we are experiencing which may or may not be related to Nginx. I am almost 100% certain that the last time we had Nginx running - we had all kinds of serious problems (high load = slow Magento websites as a result) and no apparent benefits. I don't think we need Nginx, do we? I would much rather get rid of it...**

Comment: It may actually be your php-fpm settings, which would have had to be added in addition to nginx. The settings can be difficult to tweak just right, especially if you're like me and are not a sys admin. I would look into that, I had similar problems but with Magento 2.1.9

Answer (score 0):

Connect your Magento store with SSH and use cd command to go to MAGENTO_ROOT

Run below command:

**php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall**

Also you can reindex separately as below

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute 
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price 
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url 
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat 
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat 
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product 
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext 
php shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock 
php shell/indexer.php --reindex tag_summary
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't explain things correctly though...the re-indexing while inconvenient is not the problem! What I'm looking at more is the increased load we are experiencing which may or may not be related to Nginx. I am almost 100% certain that the last time we had Nginx running - we had all kinds of serious problems (high load = slow Magento websites as a result) and no apparent benefits. I don't think we need Nginx, do we? I would much rather get rid of it...what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: There should not be problem with nginx because magento is working fine with nginx. Might you need to check your configuration you need to refer this one https://gist.github.com/gwillem/cd5ae6845fa33aa0d481

Comment: Yeah, you could forgo Nginx. However, I've found NginX to result in a smoother experience. Chances are that the configuration hasn't been optimised (still running default configs). If it's not Nginx, then I'd consider the database as the issue. As the database could be running slow enough to cause Nginx to timeout after a request is made.

Comment: Running htop in SSH should give you a good indicator if it's MySQL running slow.

Comment: @Craig How would I run htop?

Comment: @Allysin Assuming you have access via SSH. Just run `htop` (or `top`), whichever is installed on the server. If it's not installed, just run `apt-get install htop` or `yum install htop`. It's basically like Windows Task Manager. Hit `F10` to exit once you've finished looking.